# How can I specify the city in a classified ads listing?

Tags: schema.org

I have a listing of classified ads for which I use the `Product` scheme.

I want to mark also city specified in ad (with Microdata). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the documentation it looks as though *[Offer](https://schema.org/Offer)* might be a more useful schema.

Then you can use the property:

> `areaServed` - The geographic area where a service or offered item is provided.

Also the *[SellAction](https://schema.org/SellAction)* schema might be useful to you as well.